# Selection multiple variables or types with different lengths in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

So imagine I have mutiple lines of variable and their definitions in multiple lines like this (for example in flutter) :

```
 TypeA a;
 TypeABCD abcd;
 Typ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz;
```

now I want to select all of the types together or all of the variables together; I know how to select multiple line together in vscode but the problem is in this case it does not cover the specific selection of them or it selects them partly because they have different lengths. how can I select multiple variables or types or whatever in this case?

imagine what I want to select is:

```
a 
abcd 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz
```

how can I do that?

or this:

```
TypeA
TypeABCD
Typ
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. You just ask how to select multiple lines? Just drag your mouse cursor?

Comment: imagine what I want to select is:

a
abcd
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press "option" on Mac or "ctrl" on other OS to navigate cursor by word and not character.

So the trick is to do multi-cursor on each line then use word navigation to select what you want - press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `->` for example to select first word in each line **even if words are of different length**.

Its pretty hand and I use even more complex tricks to be productive, hope this helps.

Below is video showing the same.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mrw3jyhk6NEtWg4Y5p7eK5dCPCnbA8ln/view?usp=drive_link

Sample image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could hold the Alt key and drag you mouse cursor vertically from the beginning of those lines to a put a cursor on every of those lines.

Then press Ctrl+right arrow to jump to the next word in those lines

Then Ctrl+Shift+Right arrow to select those words

Comment: Yes but this will not work in case I want to select the types, because it will also select the variable parts.

Comment: @Benyamin I included video and screenshot in my answer above, did that not work?

Comment: @Benyamin if you just want the types instead of the variable just do the Ctrl+Shift+Right arrow without doing Ctrl+right arrow first...

Answer (score 1):

With a cursor on one of the lines, use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>⏶/⏷</kbd> to get a cursor on every line.

Then:

- To select variables: <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>⏴</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>⏴</kbd>
- To select types: <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>⏵</kbd>

If the types are not single words for the purposes of ctrl+arrows, you could instead do something like:

- <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>⏴</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⏴</kbd>, <kbd>⏴</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd>